# first day with angular; what am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

It is my first day and I'm trying to get a simple even workign but it isn't. Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LKktL/

```
<body ng-app>
 <div ng-controller='EventAddCtrl'>
    <p>Nothing here {{'yet' + '!'}}</p>
 <div class='first-test' ng-click="say_hello()">angular test to say hello</div>
</div>   
</body>
```

​

```
function EventAddCtrl($scope){
  $scope.say_hello = function() {
    alert('hello in there');
  }
}​
```

It's obviously not working and trying to figure out why. thx in advance

Comment: http://pkozlowskios.wordpress.com/2012/08/12/using-jsfiddle-with-angularjs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some setting problems with jsFiddle. Here is the working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LKktL/9/)

You can try [plunker](http://plnkr.co). It works pretty good like jsFiddle.

1.Add Body tag `<body ng-app>`

2.pick "no wrap (head)"

Answer (score 2):

In your JSFiddle Angular is being executed during the `onLoad` event. Open your browser console and you'll find the following error thrown by Angular

```
    Error: Argument 'EventAddCtrl' is not a function, got undefined
```

Your App has failed to initialized.

The `onLoad` event is fired at the end of the document loading process. Angular initializes your app during the `DOMContentLoaded` event, which is fired after the DOM has been parsed but **before** the DOM is ready and before the document is fully loaded. In other words, make sure the library is parsed and executed before any of those events by either including it between `<head>` or `<body>` HTML tags. A good practice is to place it just before the closing `<body>` tag.

As others have mentioned, when using JSFiddle, use either `no wrap(head)` or `no wrap(body)`.

Answer (score 1):

There are two wrong usages in your fiddle.

1. do not need to select onload, select no wrap(head) or no wrap(body) are both ok.
2. do not need to place a `<body>` tag in html panel which is already out there, and expand the **info** menu in the left panel, fill the **Body Tag** with `<body ng-app>`.

for more infomation, plz take a look at this page [fiddle documentation](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/basic/introduction.html#choose-framework).